# how to take data from the database and pass it to the common layout blade

Tags: laravel

I want to take data from the database and pass it to the common layout blade. there is no middleware for using view where so please help me to solve this problem.
thank you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use view composers which provide callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered.

```php
class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using class based composers...
        View::composer('profile', ProfileComposer::class);

        // Using closure based composers...
        View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers